# How to build GNSDK to generate Python _gnsdk.so for linux_x86-64

Tags: gracenote

I want to develop an app using gracenote SDK and python, I see the python wrapper but I need to generate or make the _gnsdk.so for linux_x86-64, how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The python wrapper currently supports mac only, but will support linux in a future GNSDK release. There is no practical way for you to generate one, please check the Gracenote Developer website for future releases.

Comment: Thank you, when the next release ? I don't find anythings on website.

Comment: We don't have a set date yet for that yet.

Comment: Any news for this?